# predictive distribution of beta

Tags: hypothesis-testing, bayesian, predictive-models, posterior

Is there a way of obtaning some kind of predictive posterior distribution for the beta model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that you have the prior $\theta \sim \beta(c, d)$ and observe $x_1, \ldots, x_N \sim \text{Geom}(\theta)$. The posterior is then given as

\begin{align}
\Pi ( \theta | x_{1:N )} &\propto \left\{ \theta^{c - 1} \cdot (1 - \theta)^{d - 1} \right\} \cdot \prod_{i = 1}^N\left\{ \theta \cdot (1 - \theta)^{x_i} \right\} \\
&\propto \theta^{c + N - 1} \cdot (1 - \theta)^{d + S - 1} \quad \text{where } S = \sum_{i = 1}^N x_i.
\end{align}

The posterior predictive distribution is then given as

\begin{align}
\Pi ( x_{N+1} | x_{1:N )} &\propto \int \left\{ \theta^{c + N - 1} \cdot (1 - \theta)^{d + S - 1} \right\} \cdot \left\{ \theta \cdot (1 - \theta)^{x_{N+1}}  \right\} \, d\theta \\
&= \int \left\{ \theta^{c + N} \cdot (1 - \theta)^{d + S + x_{N+1} - 1} \right\} \, d\theta \\
&= \frac{\Gamma(c + N + 1) \cdot \Gamma(d + S + x_{N + 1})}{\Gamma (c + d + N + S + x_{N+1} + 1)}.
\end{align}

Comment: I got exactly this expression, but is this even a probability mass function? it seems it doesn't have any probability distribution associated to it. Thanks for the work.

Comment: It is a probability mass function, because if you were to track all of the normalising constants involved, it would have to sum to one, etc. It should be a special instance of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_negative_binomial_distribution.